# Fancybox 2 - Can't Set Inline Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I'm using the following code, but the box always pops up as 100px wide with FancyBox 2.

```
<a href="#divForm" class="fancybox">Load Form</a>

<div id="divForm" style="display:none; width: 500px;" class="divform">

Just some text in here....

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({

    });
});
</script>
```

When I look at the generated code I see that fancy box seems to be adding some default settings to the wrappers.  How do I tell it to open the box at a set width?

Comment: Hi @NotaGuruAtAl. I test the same code, and it always open with "500px" as width, or whatever width I set at the "style" attribute. See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoajacobi/Da9EH/

Comment: Do you want to set the "Width" only in the JS?

Comment: Try setting 'autoSize':false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I told you in the comments, if you set the WIDTH and HEIGHT in the property "STYLE" off you div, it's opening with that WIDTH/HEIGHT.

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoajacobi/dKbp7/

If you wan't to say to the FancyBox, to open with an specific WIDTH or HEIGHT, you must use the attribute "autoSize".
JS Example:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'autoSize': false,
    'width': 200,
    'height': 140
});
```

JsFiddle Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoajacobi/mCQ5j/